# EntityFramework with Code First: Detect entity types at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

When using EntityFramework with the Code First approach, you usually derive from DbContext and create DbSet properties for all entity types you have.

I can't do this because my software can be used with modules that provide new entity types that are not known at compile time.

So I would like to determine the list of available entity types at runtime.

I got it partially working with this code:

```cs
public class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        var entityMethod = typeof(DbModelBuilder).GetMethod("Entity");

        foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            // Register all types that derive from ModelBase as entity types
            var entityTypes = assembly
                .GetTypes()
                .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ModelBase)));

            foreach (var type in entityTypes)
            {
                entityMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type)
                    .Invoke(modelBuilder, new object[] { });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I do this, `OnModelCreating` is never called. I have to add a DbSet to my class. I can not even make the DbSet private or internal, it has to be public, which makes it an ugly workaround:

```cs
public DbSet<DummyType> DummyTypes { get; set; }

public MyDbContext(string connectionName):
    base(connectionName)
{
    // Force initialization to make sure OnModelCreating
    // has been called after leaving the constructor
    DummyTypes.Count();
}
```

When adding this workaround, I can access the DbSets by calling the `DbContext.Set<EntityType>()` method, so everything works as intended.

**Question:** Is there a way to achieve the same thing without adding a public DbSet property to my class?

Comment: Your type is dynamic, so how can you use this `DbContext.Set<EntityType>()`? configuring using code can be complex, your reflection code is just simple, what about the mappings? isn't that mappings is also dynamic? Your model seems empty at compile time. So I think you can try creating your DbContext using constructor accepting a `DbCompiledModel`. DbCompiledModel can be obtained from `Compile` method of `DbModel` which can be obtained from `Build` method of `DbModelBuilder`. That means you start from a `DbModelBuilder` as an instance created any where you like.

Comment: The types are not created at runtime, they are just not known when compiling the relevant assembly. This is for a library that can be used with other assemblies which can provide new entity types. As for the mappings, I have not yet thought about that. But thanks, I will have a  look into the DbModelBuilder class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you solve your problem in a more static way? For instance, each library can also provide it own `DbContext` implementation. If libraries are statically unaware of each other, then there is no static way for them to have navigational properties to classes in other libraries. Then you can have independent `DbContexts`, one for each library. How to use them in your main code? It depends on your implementation, but I guess you can figure it out.

When libraries reference each other, there can be no loops, so, they form logical topological ordering, For instance if library A And B refer to C, you can have `DbContexts` in A and B and not in C, if it does not use its own entities.

Traditionally, there was nothing that could prevent you from doing this in EF, unless you needed migrations. Now EF [supports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn948104.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) migrations for different `DbContexts` on the same database.

Comment: I was hesitating to use multiple DbContext instances because I wanted to avoid having to call SaveChanges and similar stuff on multiple different locations, but it looks like you are right. It is easier to work around these problems than doing what I had in mind.